# Search text and scroll down with qwebview

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qwebview

I'm using Qwebview with Pyside/Qt to view an HTML page on a GUI I'm working on.

I need the possibility to add a search text function, otherwise it is useless for the purpose the GUI is made.

I've searched but I didn't find anything useful for build a code that search the text and scrolls down the page as it is made in the common browsers.
The only function I found is findText but it returns a boolean and I cannot see how it can be useful.

Do somebody have an hint / advice / guide or code for this request?

Thank you.

Comment: This is 100% possible, i have done it before. I will post back with the answer when i find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out that i had an example of this using a `QTextBrowser`, which has a lot of this built into utility functions.

You can still do it with a `QWebBrowser` though.

Bind `ctrl-f` to open a search panel, and then make it so that the search box sends out two signals;

(presuming it's a `QLineEdit`), `returnPressed`, and `textChanged`.

Each of them then calls `findText` on the `QWebPage` object.

The important part is setting the correct flag in the `findText` call (which you'll want to set with checkboxes in your search functionality, i'd say).

You set the flags so that [HighlightAllOccurrences](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#FindFlag-enum) is *not* set.

I cannot see any way to get details on a selection. Are you sure that when you do not set the `HighlightAllOccurences` flag it does not scroll to the next selection automatically?

Comment: Thank you a lot, I hade HighlightAllOccurences selected and couldn't automatically scroll to the searched text. This helped me a lot.

Comment: I didn't actually try this, it was jsut intuition. Can you confirm that when you do not include the `HighlightAllOccurences` flag it automatically scrolls to the highlighted occurence?

Comment: Yes I confirm it, it works in that way, as I was trying to do. Thank you again